# My question is in which condition $M_m=P_m$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I  have a collection of operators $\{P_m\}$ on a finite dimensional Hilbert Space which satisfies $\sum_{m} P_m= I$ where $m$  is eigen value. and I have a collection of positive definite $\{M_m\}$ which satisfies $\sum_{m} M_m^{*}M_m=I$

My question is in which condition $M_m=P_m$?

Comment: Could you clarify the part "$m$ is eigen value"? Does it mean $m$ is an eigenvalue of $P_m$, or it's the *only* eigenvalue of $P_m$? Same for $M_m$.

Comment: Yes $m$ is an eigen value for $P_m$